# Python 2.6 Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Tags: python, python-2.6

I rewrote the following Python 2.7+ code as follows for Python 2.6.

Python 2.7+

```
options = {key: value for key, value in options.items() if value is not None}
```

Python 2.6

```
options = dict((key, value) for key, value in options.items() if value is not None)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I believe that should have worked. Are you sure you parenthesized everything exactly the way you've shown us, when you actually tried to run this code? (Also, don't use the Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet button for Python. Also, eugh, Python 2.6?)

Comment: Cannot reproduce on 2.6.9.

Comment: I exactly copied the code. I am on Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in 2.6.6-- or even in 2.5.6.

Comment: Yes python2.6 ; when you are still working with RHEL6 servers, that's what you use. AFAIS it should work. Did you try transforming it into a list ? dict([...])

Comment: Can you show the full Traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking for the "SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized" in a "code wars" kata I did in 3.8.

My presumably similar example was:

```
max(word for word in x.split(), key=score)
```

I was looking for the word in the given string `x` with the highest score that was calculated by the existing but (at least here) irrelevant method named `score`. After reducing my code down to this statement, I found the problem in `word for word in x.split()` not being in parenthesized seperately from the second argument. Changing that made my code run just fine:

```
max((word for word in x.split()), key=score)
```

Since your example does not have additional arguments but there is a comma between `key` dan `value`, I assume there is a hiccup in the parser when faced with comma and generator expressions. Avoiding to unpack the item and thus removing the comma should solve the problem:

```
options = dict(item for item in options.items() if item[1] is not None)
```

We only have to fetch the value from the tuple instead of using a separate variable.